# targeting css class under element with id

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My html page structure is like this

```
<div id="myPage">
   <div class="input-group bootstrap-touchspin">
       <input id="784069" class="form-control my-class touchspin" type="text" value="0" name="784069" default-field="True" style="display: block;">
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried to fetch this element with css like this

```
#myPage .input-group .bootstrap-touchspin {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It has to be `#myPage .input-group.bootstrap-touchspin` because the space indicates the next class is a child of the previous. No space means both classes belong to the same element.

Answer (score 0):

#### Targeting the `<input>` element

If you want to target the actual `<input>` element, you should use this CSS :

```
#myPage .bootstrap-touchspin .touchspin {
    /* properties go here */
}
```

The following alternatives also all target the `<input>` element :

```
#myPage .bootstrap-touchspin input.my-class {
    /* properties go here */
}

#myPage .bootstrap-touchspin input {
    /* properties go here */
}

#myPage input.touchspin {
    /* properties go here */
}

#myPage .my-class {
    /* properties go here */
}

#784069 {
    /* properties go here */
}

...
```

#### Targeting the `<div>` element

If you want to target the `<div>` element surrounding the `<input>` element, you should use this CSS :

```
#myPage .bootstrap-touchspin {
    /* properties go here */
}
```

The following alternative should also work :

```
#myPage .input-group {
    /* properties go here */
}
```

---

#### Notes :

- There are many ways to combine different selectors, that each have their own meaning. For an overview, take a look at the [W3Schools CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).
- In the latter case (targeting the `<div>` element), you **could** use `#myPage .input-group.bootstrap-touchspin { ... }` (without the space). However, you don't really need the extra `.input-group` class because `#myPage .bootstrap-touchspin { ... }` is already pretty specific. See [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) for an introduction to CSS specificity.